# present continuous for a fixed event

Tags: verb-forms, present-continuous

I have ordered a book on the internet but I haven't paid for it yet, I must pay within one week after receiving it. I received it today, shall I email my seller:
"I **am paying** it in the next few days."?

Is present continuous the best choice as the date of payment has been planned before?

Answer (score 2):

You should use future tense. You can say:

> I will make the payment in the next few days.

Although, it is correct, but it is better to go for Future Tense.

It is not about when the payment was decided but about when the payment will take place(in your context, in the coming few days) which is future. So Future Tense is required here.

[Present Continuous Tense](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)

Comment: So If the payment takes place the day I received the book, it would be possible to use present continuous?Did I understand correctly?            What about "going to" I am going to pay in the next few days

Comment: @user5577 did you read the "Using the present continuous to talk about the future" in the link I have provided?

Comment: @user5577 If the payment take place the day you receive the book. You can use Simple Present or Present Continuous.